# Accessing top level classes from within a Java package

Tags: java, package, visibility

Say we have a project located at folder `project` with the sources in `project/src`.

We have a package `package` at `project/src/package` and classes

- `TopClass` in `project/src/TopClass.java`, and
- `PackageClass` in `project/src/package/PackageClass.java`.

Now we want to evoke the constructor of `TopClass` inside of `PackageClass`, but said constructor (although declared `public`) seems to be not invisible inside of the package.

Do we need to import it somehow? How can we access it?

Comment: `project/src/PackageClass.java` or `project/src/package/PackageClass.java`?

Comment: @BenWin The latter, of course. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified that it is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.

So to archieve what you are trying to do, you have to use some kind of indirect class access, like reflections API:

```
Class sampleClass = Class.forName("SampleClass");
Method sampleMethod = sampleClass.getMethod("sampleMethod" , new Class[] { String.class });
sampleMethod.invoke(sampleClass.newInstance(), "It works!");
```

with the default package class:

```
public class SampleClass {
    public void sampleMethod(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the urge to downvote this answer merely for the consequences its content has. (+1)

Comment: :). Atleast you wont spend more time trying to fix this issue. Maybe you could accept the answer, so we can treat this topic as solved.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Your answer doesn’t offer a full solution or a reference to a solution. I think you should include that – otherwise it isn’t fully resolved.

Comment: Well i added a simple approach for you.